# Can someone help me with this hotkey script?

Tags: keydown, hotkeys, pixel, mousemove

Okay so i wanted to make a script that when the hotkey is pressed it moves your mouse down a few pixels.
I've tried to do it myself but i just don't understand it.

It can be a script or program

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#m::
MouseMove, 0, 3, 50, R
```

This will move the mouse cursor down three pixels from its current location at a slow speed. The hotkey (windows key + m) is assigned.

Reference:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm

Comment: Noob question: how would i make this work with a hotkey?

Comment: I have edited the above answer to answer your question.